# Displaying popup menu with user data (Orchard)

Tags: c#, menu, orchardcms

I am trying to improve a custom part that is part of our corporate Orchard site.  It is  a popup menu which displays the user's username, profile image, and a menu.  Currently, the username and profile image are retrieved from a Profile module we wrote, and the menu part is just static text hard coded in the template.  I would like to change this to use an Orchard menu to get the menu items.  I've been trying to do this by getting the a menu widget and then rendering that content into part of the shape for display in the template:

```
WidgetPart widget = _widgetService.GetWidgets().Where(w => w.Title == "Profile Menu").SingleOrDefault();
if (widget == null)
    throw new Exception("Not found");
dynamic menuText = _contentManager.BuildDisplay((ContentItem)widget.ContentItem); 

//...

return ContentShape("Parts_ProfileHeader", () => shapeHelper.Parts_ProfileHeader(
    FullName: fullname, 
    ImageUrl: imageUrl,
    ImageHeight: imageHeight,
    ImageWidth: imageWidth,
    Menu: menuText
    ));
```

But this resulted in a stackoverflow exception.  I also tried retrieving the menupart using the MenuService and passing that to the template, but that only displayed the menu title.

The template displays the user-specific info, and also contains the .showBalloon & .hideBalloon calls to make the menu pop up.

Is there a better way to do this, or a way to do it purely with Orchard parts?

Comment: Just look at your code as it appears now. Please format it so we can actually read it: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks, Jim, for fixing it for me.